# Creating database objects dynamically based on `datetime`s?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So say I have a `TimeSlot` object, (which is supposed to represent an interview timeslot), and I have a range of times that I want the timeslots to fill. Say I want to fill timeslots tomorrow from 10AM - 5PM, in 30 minute increments (i.e. 14 total slots).

A TimeSlot object has two `datetime` attributes, one that represents the starting time and one that represents the ending time.

I want the administrator of my app to be able to input two `datetime`'s and an `incrementlength` (i.e. 30 minutes), and I want to dynamically generate a collection of `TimeSlot` objects in my database that represent the specified range of time, cut up into increments of `incrementlength` minutes. For instance, the TimeSlots generated by the above example would be:

10AM - 10:30AM/10:30AM - 11AM/etc.

Where would I define such a method, how exactly would I create `TimeSlot` objects within the method, and how would I enable an admin to call such a method? Sorry, I just don't really know where to begin. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You whould define that in the model and it will be a class method because its not assigned to one object of the class but to the class itself. I whould solve it like this

```
def self.create_by_interval(start_time, end_time, intervall)
  ((end_time.to_i-start_time.to_i)/(intervall*60)).floor.times do |factor|
     TimeSlot.create(:start => start_time+(factor*intervall).minutes, :end_time => start_time+((factor+1)*intervall).minutes)
   end
end
```

When you call `to_i` on a Date its converted to a unix timestamp so `end_time.to_i-start_time.to_i` calculates the secounds between start and end date. These seconds are devided by the interval to determine how many objects are needed. THe `floor` methods rounds a `Float` down because you cant create 1.99 calendar objects ;)

I wrote this from my head it might not be perfect but it should make clear how it can be done.

// You need to create a form that submits the data needed. Then you can handle the data in the action that receives the entered data in the `params?` hash. Your form could look like this:

```
<%= form_for :date_range, :url => working_path_helper do |f| %>
  <%= f-label :start_time %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :start_time %><br />
  <%= f-label :end_time %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :end_time %><br />
  <%= f-label :intervall %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :intervall %><br />
  <%= f.submit %>  
<% end %>
```

Then in the controller you need to call the class Method like This:

```
TimeSlot.create_by_interval(Time.parse(params[:date_range][:start_time]), Time.parse(params[:date_range][:end_time]), params[:date_range][:intervall])
```

The `Time.parse` method returns a time object basedon a string because you cant transfer anything else then strings over http.

Comment: Excellent thank you! This makes sense; however, how would I actually call this class method? Say I have a view that only my admin can access; do I just create a form and set the inputs of the form equal to the arguments of the class method? I've scoured the web but can't really find a definitive example of this being done syntactically.